# UIPageViewController Doesn't Update ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to use `UIPageViewController`, and the slide is taken to account in debug, but the pages don't update:

```
import UIKit

class TutorialPageViewController: UIPageViewController {

private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return [UINib(nibName: "FinansicalTradingViewController", bundle:nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as? FinansicalTradingViewController,
            UINib(nibName: "VideoViewController", bundle:nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as? VideoViewController,
            UINib(nibName: "AllowZeroViewController", bundle:nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as? AllowZeroViewController,
            UINib(nibName: "TutorialStartViewController", bundle:nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as? TutorialStartViewController]
    }() as! [UIViewController]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataSource = self

    //        let vc = UINib(nibName: "VideoViewController", bundle:nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as? VideoViewController
    //        setViewControllers([vc!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
        setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                           direction: .forward,
                           animated: true,
                           completion: nil)
    }

  }

}
```

---

```
extension TutorialPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                        viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return nil
    }

    guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                        viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
    let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count

    guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
}
```

Comment: *"but the pages don't update"* ... Can you clarify that? Does your **first** page show up? When you begin to swipe to the next page, does the current page move left, but an Empty page comes in from the right? Or can you not scroll at all?

Comment: Yeah, the first page appears, I swipe to the right side(finger goes from right to left) and the method 'viewControllerAfter' is called, but the page it shows me is still the same page

Comment: So, if you put a BreakPoint on the first line in `viewControllerAfter` and step through... is the index value correct? Are you getting past the `guard`s and `nextIndex ` on the final line is actually the correct "+1" value?

Comment: @DonMag Yes it is.